# Datetime format in flask marshmallow schema

Tags: python, datetime, flask-sqlalchemy, datetime-format, marshmallow

I want to apply a custom DateTime format for the data retrieved from model using the Schema in flask marshmallow.

Currently using the schema like:

```
class ScheduleListSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'start_time', 'end_time')
```

In this `start_time` in format of `2018-12-05T03:00:00+00:00`

So I want to create a custom format for the `start_time` value in schema.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the code like this:

`start_time = fields.fields.DateTime(format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')`

Answer (score 2):

If `end_time` is the same format as `start_time` , `datetimeformat` is another solution:

```
class ScheduleListSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'start_time', 'end_time')
        datetimeformat = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
```

Comment: `Meta.dateformat` works for `fields.Date`. For `fields.DateTime` now you have to use `Meta.datetimeformat`. Source: https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/issues/1223

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z` format does not give an absolutely correctly ISO 8061 formatted datetime string.

I will give an example below to demonstrate the difference:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
'2023-03-12T13:47:33.983358+0000'

>>> datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()
'2023-03-12T13:47:45.994597+00:00'
```

As you can see, the time shift relative to the Greenwich meridian in the first case is written in conjunction, and in the second case the hours and minutes are separated by a colon. Exactly the second case fully corresponds to ISO 8061.

You could define 'start_time' as a [Function](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/api_reference.html#marshmallow.fields.Function) field:

```
from datetime import datetime

class ScheduleListSchema(ma.Schema):
    start_time = fields.Function(lambda obj: obj.start_time.isoformat())
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'end_time')
```